# Why is the unsolved-mysteries tag even allowed?

Tags: discussion

Well, unsolved mysteries are well, unsolved.

[The 2 million, er, 20 dollar problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17106/the-2-million-er-20-dollar-problem)

That on in particular, I don't know why the tag is included.

The other ones? UNSOLVED!

Well, one got answered with a +1. But that was copied off of somewhere else.

So why are they even there?